# logging to an account via httpclient and httppost

Tags: java, android, authentication, httpclient

hey guys i'm working on a project which deals with a user entering username and password then they should sign in to their email accounts.i've searched the net but my problem is that though i think i know how to login the user but i don't know what to do from there

here goes that part of my code:

```
private class AsyncTaskOperation extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>
{

     private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
     String ciao="";
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Display the loading spinner
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait.. ");
        Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        Dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);


        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... paramsObj) {
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
            "https://www.elenoon.ir/mail/");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user.getText()
            .toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass.getText()
            .toString()));

    try {

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse execute = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        InputStream content;
        content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                content));
        String s = "";
        String test = "";
        while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            test += s;
        }
        if (test.contains("U")) {
            // reset field and toast
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Failed",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Form.class);
            // this.startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Successful",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) 
    {
        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();
        // Do actions after end of the HTTPGet or POST Method

    } // End of method onPostExecute
```

the question is now how should i know that the server has logged in the user and then how can i use it to show another activity for user where he can see his own mails.thank you so much i'm really in need :)))

Answer (score 0):

To login the user on the Server you can try something like this. Wrap the `getCurrentUser()` API method to detect if it sees a null user and force a login in that case.

Inside the `doGet method`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
  UserService userService=UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
  User user=userService.getCurrentUser();
  if (user != null) {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, " + user.getNickname());
  }else {
    //Redirecting to createLoginURL method will force the user to login.
    resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
  }
}
```

To make the login successful and advance to main Activity, in `onPostExecute`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    mAuthTask = null;
    showProgress(false);
    if (success) {
        finish();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MyMainActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    } else {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
        mPasswordView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

for more details, check here: [Login Activity Template generated activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209046/fix-android-studio-login-activity-template-generated-activity)